# Как использовать любой адрес с подсети IPv6?

Tags: linux, centos, ipv6

Есть сеть /64 на VPS. Адресов там очень много, но чтобы использовать какой-то из них (в ping/curl) нужно его отдельно добавлять на интерфейс. Как можно этого избежать? Нужны именно одномоментно все адреса из сети.

Все инструкции, которая всего одна на самом деле (https://blog.vpsville.ru/blog/howto/133.html) не работает, к сожалению.

OS - CentOS 7.

P.S. Не думал, что такая проблема вообще будет. Хостер тоже не может помочь.

Comment: А можно нескромный вопрос, зачем вам все? Лично мне всегда хватало двух

Comment: ну так очевидно - запускать парсилки/ддосилки, которых с той стороны по айпи блокируют.

Comment: Не совсем парсинг/DDoS, но да. около того :)

Comment: неужели спам? а люди то и не в курсе, что ipv6 можно сразу банить пачками

Comment: Ничего того что кому-то может как-то навредить там нет, но это вообще темы не касается. Да и в блокировку ничего не планируется уводить, просто нужно иметь возможность использовать любой адрес с подсети IPv6.

Comment: так добавь все адреса на интерфейс и используй)